# Read PNG file and convert to Image

Tags: c#, android, image, xamarin

I have a server (in java) which contain different image that I can serve to client(in C# using xamarin). 
On the client side, once I received the data I want to display the image but I'm not sure how.

Here is what I've tried on the client side, but I get an error(RuntimeException) during the conversion.

```
string responseImage = executeRequest("/image/category", category, "GET");
                byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(responseImage);
                var drawable = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(data, 0, data.Leng
```

the responseImage is the png data looks like the following

```
"�PNG\0\0\0IHDR\0\0�\0\0\0�\b\0\0\0g���\0\0\0sRGB\0���\0\0\0gAMA\0\0��\v�a\0\0\0\tpHYs\0\0�\0\0��o�d\0\0��IDATx^佇b#I�mY_�S\"…"
```

Comment: That doesn't seems to be a Base64String

Comment: Seems like `responseImage` is a byte array.

Comment: That looks like a PNG image as there is PNG in it. Save the array to file and inspect with an image viewer. Show the logcat and tell which statement causes the error.

Comment: 'the response image looks'. Please come to the point: What is the response image in your code? Please add a xamarin tag to your code.

Comment: @William does the image saved as byte array?

Comment: @greenapps I tried the save responseImage as png file in external storage, but it showed as borken file